# Adding foreign characters to a cufon font

Tags: javascript, html, localization, fonts, cufon

I'm using gettext with python and google app engine and a cufón font and I lose international characters and I can't display åäö for certain words eg to the left here it should say FÖLJ instead of FLJ:

[image]

The gettext translation .po that I compile to .mo with poedit contains this translation:

```
msgid "FOLLOW US"
msgstr "FÖLJ OSS"

msgid "DISTRIBUTOR"
msgstr "ÅTERFÖRSÄLJARE"
```

So one is working and not the other because the cufón font does not have åäö. The template is

```
<div class="links"> <a href="/login/" target="_blank" title="Log in distributor">&nbsp;{% trans %}DISTRIBUTOR{% endtrans %} LOG IN</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/register/" target="_blank" title="Log in distributor">{% trans %}JOIN{% endtrans %}</a>    
            <strong class="title">{% trans %}FOLLOW US{% endtrans %}</strong>
```

And my cufon font is this rather large [file](http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/js/cufon.js)

```
Cufon.registerFont({"w":216,"face":{"font-family":"ApexLight","font-weight":450,"font-stretch":"normal","units-per-em":"360","panose-1":"2 1 6 0 4 5 1 1 1 3","ascent":"270","descent":"-90","x-height":"2","bbox":"-14 -288.35 333 92","underline-thickness":"7.2","underline-position":"-29.52","unicode-range":"U+0020-U+007E"},"glyphs":{" ":{"w":61,"k":{"T":11,"V":7,"W":7,"Y":4}},"A":{"d":"208,0r-14,0r-27,-78r-118,0r-27,78r-13,0r95,-272r8,0xm108,-252r-56,164r112,0","k":{"T":34,"V":32,"W":22,"Y":47,"C":7,"G":7,"O":7,"Q":7,"S":7,"v":20,"w":7,"y":18,"c":4,"d":4,"e":4,"o":4,"q":4,"U":7}},"B":{"d":"25,0r0,-270r82,0v61,0,81,30,81,68v0,32,-19,58,-52,61v42,0,62,30,62,68v0,41,-23,73,-88,73r-85,0xm37,-135r0,125r76,0v60,0,73,-31,73,-63v0,-73,-79,-62,-149,-62xm177,-202v0,-30,-9,-58,-66,-58r-74,0r0,115r76,0v50,0,64,-28,64,-57","w":212,"k":{"V":11,"W":4,"Y":7,"X":7}},"C":{"d":"20,-135v0,-87,24,-137,104,-137v31,0,52,5,66,11r0,11v-22,-8,-40,-11,-66,-11v-67,0,-93,42,-93,126v0,84,26,126,93,126v26,0,44,-3,66,-11r0,11v-14,6,-35,11,-66,11v-80,0,-104,-50,-104,-137","w":210,"k":{"T":7,"Y":11,"A":4}},"D":{"d":"103,0r-78,0r0,-270r78,0v85,0,104,50,104,135v0,85,-19,135,-104,135xm37,-260r0,250r65,0v75,0,93,-41,93,-125v0,-84,-18,-125,-93,-125r-65,0","w":226,"k":{"T":7,"V":11,"W":7,"Y":25,"A":11,"X":11}},"E":{"d":"162,-145r0,10r-125,0r0,125r138,0r0,10r-150,0r0,-270r150,0r0,10r-138,0r0,115r125,0","w":194,"k":{"J":-5,"j":-5}},"F":{"d":"158,-145r0,10r-121,0r0,135r-12,0r0,-270r146,0r0,10r-134,0r0,115r121,0","w":185,"k":{".":36,",":36,":":13,";":13,"A":22,"J":22,"v":7,"w":7,"y":7,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"g":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"X":7}},"G":{"d":"124,-9v23,0,50,-3,68,-12r0,-104r-58,0r0,-10r70,0r0,123v-18,8,-44,14,-80,14v-80,0,-104,-50,-104,-137v0,-87,24,-137,104,-137v35,0,57,6,72,13r0,11v-22,-9,-43,-13,-72,-13v-67,0,-93,42,-93,126v0,84,26,126,93,126","w":228,"k":{"T":7,"Y":7,"A":4}},"H":{"d":"203,0r-11,0r0,-135r-155,0r0,135r-12,0r0,-270r12,0r0,125r155,0r0,-125r11,0r0,270","w":228},"I":{"d":"45,0r-12,0r0,-270r12,0r0,270","w":77},"J":{"d":"11,1r0,-10v32,3,68,-1,68,-38r0,-223r11,0r0,222v3,37,-32,55,-79,49","w":126},"K":{"d":"68,-143r-32,38r0,105r-11,0r0,-270r11,0r0,151r130,-151r13,0r-104,120r117,150r-14,0","w":197,"k":{"V":7,"W":7,"Y":7,"C":14,"G":14,"O":14,"Q":14,"S":7,"v":29,"w":22,"y":22,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"l":7,"f":18,"i":7,"t":22,"u":7,"x":7,"z":7}},"L":{"d":"36,-270r0,260r131,0r0,10r-142,0r0,-270r11,0","w":176,"k":{"T":36,"V":47,"W":36,"Y":52,"C":18,"G":18,"O":18,"Q":18,"v":25,"w":18,"X":7}},"M":{"d":"130,-37r-93,-197r0,234r-12,0r0,-270r8,0r102,220r102,-220r8,0r0,270r-12,0r0,-234r-93,197r-10,0","w":270},"N":{"d":"207,0r-8,0r-163,-245r1,245r-12,0r0,-270r7,0r163,245r0,-245r12,0r0,270","w":231},"O":{"d":"217,-135v0,82,-13,137,-99,137v-86,0,-98,-55,-98,-137v0,-82,12,-137,98,-137v86,0,99,55,99,137xm206,-135v0,-83,-14,-126,-88,-126v-74,0,-87,43,-87,126v0,83,13,126,87,126v74,0,88,-43,88,-126","w":236,"k":{"T":14,"V":7,"Y":11,"A":7,"X":7}},"P":{"d":"109,-270v66,0,83,37,83,78v0,41,-17,78,-83,78r-72,0r0,114r-12,0r0,-270r84,0xm37,-260r0,136r74,0v60,0,69,-37,69,-68v0,-31,-9,-68,-69,-68r-74,0","w":202,"k":{".":50,",":50,"V":11,"W":4,"Y":7,"A":27,"v":5,"w":4,"a":11,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"g":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"X":7,"u":4,"z":7,"m":7,"n":7,"p":7,"r":7}},"Q":{"d":"217,-135v0,79,-13,129,-87,137r123,28r0,13r-168,-45v-57,-15,-65,-64,-65,-133v0,-82,12,-137,98,-137v86,0,99,55,99,137xm206,-135v0,-83,-14,-126,-88,-126v-74,0,-87,43,-87,126v0,83,13,126,87,126v74,0,88,-43,88,-126","w":236,"k":{"T":14,"V":7,"Y":11,"A":7,"X":7}},"R":{"d":"37,-125r0,125r-12,0r0,-270r85,0v67,0,82,27,82,73v0,40,-11,65,-57,71r68,126r-14,0r-66,-125r-86,0xm37,-135r79,0v57,0,65,-27,65,-62v0,-35,-8,-63,-65,-63r-79,0r0,125","w":209,"k":{"T":14,"V":14,"Y":14}},"S":{"d":"109,-272v31,0,52,5,66,11r0,11v-22,-8,-40,-11,-66,-11v-62,0,-77,27,-77,59v0,44,19,51,75,57v54,6,80,13,80,70v0,36,-17,77,-97,77v-23,0,-55,-5,-72,-12r0,-11v17,6,38,12,72,12v66,0,86,-29,86,-66v0,-46,-12,-53,-72,-60v-58,-6,-83,-17,-83,-67v0,-34,17,-70,88,-70","w":204,"k":{"T":11,"V":7,"W":7,"Y":11,"A":7,"X":7,"Z":7}},"T":{"d":"179,-260r-78,0r0,260r-12,0r0,-260r-78,0r0,-10r168,0r0,10","w":190,"k":{".":32,",":32,":":32,";":32,"A":29,"C":11,"G":11,"J":22,"O":11,"Q":11,"v":29,"w":29,"y":29,"a":32,"c":32,"d":32,"e":32,"g":32,"o":32,"q":32,"s":32," ":11,"j":7,"f":18,"i":7,"t":18,"u":29,"x":29,"z":29,"m":29,"n":29,"p":29,"r":29}},"U":{"d":"116,-9v53,0,81,-17,81,-79r0,-182r11,0r0,183v0,75,-42,89,-92,89v-50,0,-93,-14,-93,-89r0,-183r12,0r0,182v0,62,28,79,81,79","w":231,"k":{"A":7}},"V":{"d":"195,-270r13,0r-96,272r-8,0r-95,-272r13,0r86,252","k":{".":36,",":36,":":27,";":27,"A":32,"C":7,"G":7,"O":7,"Q":7,"v":13,"w":13,"y":13,"a":32,"c":29,"d":29,"e":29,"g":29,"o":29,"q":29,"s":25," ":11,"f":7,"t":7,"u":14,"x":13,"z":13,"m":13,"n":13,"p":13,"r":13}},"W":{"d":"211,2r-66,-249r-65,249r-9,0r-62,-272r12,0r55,250r64,-250r10,0r65,250r55,-250r12,0r-62,272r-9,0","w":290,"k":{".":36,",":36,":":27,";":27,"A":22,"a":16,"c":14,"d":14,"e":14,"g":14,"o":14,"q":14,"s":14," ":11,"t":7,"u":7,"z":7,"m":14,"n":14,"p":14,"r":14}},"X":{"d":"104,-145r79,-125r15,0r-88,133r91,137r-16,0r-81,-128r-82,128r-15,0r90,-137r-87,-133r14,0","w":207,"k":{"C":7,"G":7,"O":7,"Q":7,"v":14,"w":11,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"x":7,"z":7,"m":7,"n":7,"p":7,"r":7}},"Y":{"d":"213,-270r-96,159r0,111r-12,0r0,-111r-96,-159r14,0r88,149r88,-149r14,0","w":222,"k":{".":43,",":43,":":34,";":34,"A":47,"C":14,"G":14,"J":29,"O":14,"Q":14,"S":11,"v":29,"w":29,"y":29,"a":50,"c":45,"d":45,"e":45,"g":45,"o":45,"q":45,"s":40,"l":5," ":7,"j":13,"f":25,"i":13,"t":25,"u":29,"x":29,"z":29,"m":29,"n":29,"p":29,"r":29}},"Z":{"d":"198,0r-185,0r0,-8r166,-252r-159,0r0,-10r173,0r0,8r-167,252r172,0r0,10","w":210,"k":{"v":14,"w":14,"y":14,"f":7,"t":7}},"a":{"d":"88,-172v-26,0,-45,4,-52,7r0,-9v10,-4,31,-8,52,-8v55,0,66,23,66,58r0,124v-10,2,-8,-9,-11,-14v-15,11,-43,16,-61,16v-46,0,-62,-26,-62,-55v0,-27,13,-52,63,-55r59,-4v1,-42,-4,-61,-54,-60xm142,-102v-47,2,-111,1,-111,49v0,21,8,45,52,45v23,0,43,-6,59,-16r0,-78","w":177},"b":{"d":"98,-182v60,0,74,40,74,92v0,52,-14,92,-74,92v-21,0,-47,-6,-63,-16v-3,5,-1,15,-10,14r0,-270r11,0r0,103v16,-10,42,-15,62,-15xm98,-8v54,0,63,-41,63,-82v0,-41,-9,-82,-63,-82v-25,0,-46,5,-62,15r0,134v16,10,37,15,62,15","w":194,"k":{"v":4,"w":7,"y":7,"x":7}},"c":{"d":"22,-90v0,-54,14,-92,74,-92v16,0,36,2,50,7r0,10v-13,-4,-27,-7,-50,-7v-54,0,-63,40,-63,82v0,42,9,82,63,82v23,0,37,-3,50,-7r0,10v-14,5,-34,7,-50,7v-60,0,-74,-38,-74,-92","w":164},"d":{"d":"96,-182v20,0,46,5,62,15r0,-103r11,0r0,270v-9,1,-7,-9,-10,-14v-16,10,-42,16,-63,16v-60,0,-74,-40,-74,-92v0,-52,14,-92,74,-92xm96,-8v25,0,46,-5,62,-15r0,-134v-16,-10,-37,-15,-62,-15v-54,0,-63,41,-63,82v0,41,9,82,63,82","w":194},"e":{"d":"96,-8v27,0,44,-5,57,-9r0,10v-14,5,-38,9,-57,9v-60,0,-74,-38,-74,-92v0,-54,14,-92,74,-92v62,0,66,42,66,97r-129,0v1,41,12,77,63,77xm33,-95r119,0v0,-39,-5,-77,-56,-77v-51,0,-62,36,-63,77","w":183,"k":{"v":4,"w":4,"y":7,"x":7}},"f":{"d":"43,0r0,-170r-34,0r0,-6r34,-4v-9,-65,16,-102,85,-90r0,9v-36,-4,-74,1,-74,40r0,41r62,0r0,10r-62,0r0,170r-11,0","w":133,"k":{".":22,",":22,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"o":7,"q":7}},"g":{"d":"152,-118v0,51,-46,76,-97,59v-19,7,-17,39,6,37v46,9,120,0,120,55v0,42,-46,59,-95,59v-50,0,-82,-12,-82,-51v0,-30,25,-48,49,-55v-29,-3,-26,-40,-7,-49v-43,-28,-36,-128,40,-119v27,3,55,2,84,2r0,10r-40,-1v16,11,22,30,22,53xm15,41v0,32,26,41,71,41v43,0,84,-13,84,-49v0,-46,-65,-36,-102,-45v-22,6,-53,21,-53,53xm86,-172v-47,0,-55,26,-55,54v0,28,8,54,55,54v47,0,55,-26,55,-54v0,-28,-8,-54,-55,-54","w":183},"h":{"d":"25,0r0,-270r11,0r0,104v39,-24,122,-28,122,35r0,131r-11,0r0,-132v3,-58,-81,-42,-111,-25r0,157r-11,0","w":181},"i":{"d":"63,-7r0,9v-19,0,-27,-8,-27,-26r0,-156r10,0r0,155v0,14,4,18,17,18xm30,-234v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,11,5,11,11v0,6,-5,11,-11,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11","w":86},"j":{"d":"-14,92r0,-10v27,0,50,-8,50,-36r0,-226r10,0r0,224v0,32,-20,48,-60,48xm30,-234v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,11,5,11,11v0,6,-5,11,-11,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11","w":82},"k":{"d":"149,-180r-75,72r89,108r-14,0r-82,-101r-32,30r1,71r-11,0r0,-270r11,0r-1,186r100,-96r14,0","w":168,"k":{"a":7,"c":11,"d":11,"e":11,"g":7,"o":11,"q":11,"l":7,"f":5,"i":7,"t":5,"u":5}},"l":{"d":"63,-7r0,9v-19,0,-27,-8,-27,-26r0,-246r10,0r0,245v0,14,4,18,17,18","w":86},"m":{"d":"134,0r0,-136v4,-56,-72,-36,-97,-21r0,157r-12,0r0,-180v10,-2,8,9,11,14v27,-18,89,-25,104,3v40,-28,113,-31,113,28r0,135r-11,0r0,-136v1,-57,-70,-36,-99,-18v5,47,1,103,2,154r-11,0","w":276},"n":{"d":"147,0r0,-132v4,-58,-80,-42,-110,-25r0,157r-12,0r0,-180v10,-2,8,9,11,14v38,-23,123,-29,123,35r0,131r-12,0","w":182},"o":{"d":"22,-90v0,-53,11,-92,74,-92v63,0,74,39,74,92v0,53,-11,92,-74,92v-63,0,-74,-39,-74,-92xm33,-90v0,45,6,82,63,82v57,0,63,-37,63,-82v0,-45,-6,-82,-63,-82v-57,0,-63,37,-63,82","w":191,"k":{"v":4,"w":4,"y":7,"x":7}},"p":{"d":"98,2v-20,0,-46,-5,-62,-15r0,103r-11,0r0,-270v9,-1,7,9,10,14v16,-10,42,-16,63,-16v60,0,74,40,74,92v0,52,-14,92,-74,92xm98,-172v-25,0,-46,5,-62,15r0,134v16,10,37,15,62,15v54,0,63,-41,63,-82v0,-41,-9,-82,-63,-82","w":194,"k":{"v":4,"w":4,"y":7,"x":7}},"q":{"d":"96,2v-60,0,-74,-40,-74,-92v0,-52,14,-92,74,-92v21,0,47,6,63,16v3,-5,1,-15,10,-14r0,270r-11,0r0,-103v-16,10,-42,15,-62,15xm96,-172v-54,0,-63,41,-63,82v0,41,9,82,63,82v25,0,46,-5,62,-15r0,-134v-16,-10,-37,-15,-62,-15","w":194},"r":{"d":"117,-181r0,10v-30,-3,-61,2,-80,14r0,157r-12,0r0,-180v10,-2,8,9,11,14v21,-12,52,-19,81,-15","w":127,"k":{".":22,",":22,"a":7}},"s":{"d":"72,-8v47,0,60,-18,60,-40v0,-26,-8,-36,-50,-41v-48,-6,-59,-17,-59,-45v-10,-45,71,-58,116,-41r0,10v-13,-4,-27,-7,-50,-7v-41,0,-55,14,-55,38v0,26,12,31,50,36v47,6,59,17,59,49v0,26,-16,51,-71,51v-16,0,-36,-2,-50,-7r0,-10v13,4,27,7,50,7","w":162},"t":{"d":"104,-7v6,-2,4,5,4,9v-41,1,-66,-15,-65,-48r0,-124r-34,0r0,-6r34,-4r0,-54r11,-1r0,55r62,0r0,10r-62,0r0,126v0,28,23,37,50,37","w":133},"u":{"d":"35,-180r0,132v-4,58,80,42,110,25r0,-157r12,0r0,180v-9,1,-7,-9,-10,-14v-39,23,-124,29,-124,-35r0,-131r12,0","w":182},"v":{"d":"9,-180r13,0r61,163r62,-163r12,0r-71,182r-5,0","w":166,"k":{".":29,",":29,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"g":7,"o":7,"q":7}},"w":{"d":"126,-180r50,163r43,-163r12,0r-51,182r-9,0r-51,-168r-52,168r-8,0r-51,-182r12,0r43,163r49,-163r13,0","w":239,"k":{".":22,",":22,"a":5,"c":4,"d":4,"e":4,"g":4,"o":4,"q":4}},"x":{"d":"77,-85r-59,85r-13,0r66,-93r-61,-87r12,0r55,79r55,-79r12,0r-61,87r66,93r-13,0","w":154,"k":{"a":7,"c":11,"d":11,"e":11,"g":7,"o":11,"q":11,"l":7,"f":5,"i":7,"t":5,"u":5}},"y":{"d":"9,-180r13,0r61,165r62,-165r12,0r-105,270r-12,0r38,-92","w":166,"k":{".":29,",":29,"c":4,"d":4,"e":4,"o":4,"q":4}},"z":{"d":"149,0r-136,0r0,-7r119,-164r-114,0r0,-9r127,0r0,7r-120,164r124,0r0,9","w":161,"k":{"a":4,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"o":7,"q":7}},"&":{"d":"69,-147v-25,-46,-35,-125,40,-125v43,0,57,29,57,56v1,41,-43,55,-82,74v23,41,60,77,96,100v30,-30,48,-78,48,-138r11,0v0,63,-18,113,-49,144v19,11,39,20,61,29r-3,9v-23,-9,-44,-20,-65,-32v-48,45,-171,53,-171,-39v0,-46,25,-62,57,-78xm173,-35v-38,-23,-74,-62,-99,-103v-32,15,-51,29,-51,69v0,82,107,70,150,34xm79,-151v34,-16,76,-29,76,-65v0,-24,-10,-46,-46,-46v-67,2,-49,72,-30,111","w":261},"`":{"d":"106,-198r-7,0r-27,-72r13,0","w":205},".":{"d":"23,-9v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,11,5,11,11v0,6,-5,11,-11,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11","w":68,"k":{"T":32,"V":32,"W":29,"Y":29,"v":14,"w":11,"y":14}},",":{"d":"26,-18r16,0r-17,63r-7,0","w":68,"k":{"T":32,"V":32,"W":29,"Y":29,"v":14,"w":11,"y":14}},":":{"d":"23,-135v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,11,5,11,11v0,6,-5,11,-11,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11xm23,-9v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,11,5,11,11v0,6,-5,11,-11,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11","w":68,"k":{"T":32,"V":27,"W":29,"Y":29}},";":{"d":"23,-135v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,11,5,11,11v0,6,-5,11,-11,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11xm26,-18r16,0r-17,63r-7,0","w":68,"k":{"T":32,"V":27,"W":29,"Y":29}},"!":{"d":"37,-76r-6,0r-5,-194r16,0xm23,-9v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,11,5,11,11v0,6,-5,11,-11,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11","w":68},"?":{"d":"49,-76v-21,-85,91,-42,91,-126v0,-33,-13,-60,-77,-60v-22,0,-40,5,-52,8r0,-10v12,-4,37,-8,52,-8v76,0,88,34,88,70v0,53,-26,58,-66,74v-31,13,-31,24,-30,52r-6,0xm48,-9v0,-6,5,-11,11,-11v6,0,10,5,10,11v0,6,-4,11,-10,11v-6,0,-11,-5,-11,-11","w":169},"\/":{"d":"12,72r-12,0r124,-360r12,0","w":136},"\\":{"d":"136,72r-12,0r-124,-360r12,0","w":136},"|":{"d":"45,72r-12,0r0,-360r12,0r0,360","w":77},"-":{"d":"103,-128r0,10r-83,0r0,-10r83,0","w":122},"(":{"d":"25,-108v0,-87,24,-150,42,-180r13,0v-18,29,-43,93,-43,180v0,87,25,151,43,180r-13,0v-18,-30,-42,-93,-42,-180","w":100},")":{"d":"76,-108v0,87,-25,150,-43,180r-12,0v18,-29,43,-93,43,-180v0,-87,-25,-151,-43,-180r12,0v18,30,43,93,43,180","w":100},"[":{"d":"44,-278r0,340r38,0r0,10r-49,0r0,-360r49,0r0,10r-38,0","w":100},"]":{"d":"57,62r0,-340r-38,0r0,-10r49,0r0,360r-49,0r0,-10r38,0","w":100},"{":{"d":"40,-108v11,3,19,12,18,29r-7,118v-1,18,11,24,31,23v0,5,1,12,-6,10v-22,0,-37,-10,-36,-34r6,-118v2,-17,-9,-24,-28,-23v0,-5,-1,-12,6,-10v16,0,23,-8,22,-23r-6,-118v-1,-26,16,-35,42,-34v0,5,1,12,-6,10v-17,0,-26,7,-25,23r7,118v1,17,-7,26,-18,29","w":100},"}":{"d":"60,-108v-11,-3,-18,-12,-17,-29r6,-118v2,-18,-10,-24,-30,-23v0,-5,-1,-12,6,-10v22,0,37,10,36,34r-6,118v-2,18,9,25,28,23v0,6,1,12,-7,10v-16,0,-22,8,-21,23r6,118v1,26,-16,35,-42,34v0,-5,-1,-12,6,-10v17,0,25,-7,24,-23r-6,-118v-1,-17,6,-26,17,-29","w":100},"*":{"d":"66,-225r-3,0r-5,-45r12,0xm129,-219v-15,1,-34,11,-46,7r42,-19xm51,-189r3,2r-23,39r-10,-7xm98,-148v-6,-13,-22,-29,-21,-41r31,34xm45,-212v-11,4,-31,-6,-45,-7r4,-12","w":127},"^":{"d":"33,-180r-8,0r65,-90r10,0r66,90r-8,0r-63,-80","w":183},"~":{"d":"123,-114v18,0,30,-9,35,-14v2,21,-15,23,-35,23v-37,0,-38,-26,-69,-26v-18,0,-31,8,-36,13v-2,-21,15,-23,35,-23v37,0,39,27,70,27","w":176},"_":{"d":"104,80r0,10r-104,0r0,-10r104,0","w":104},"'":{"d":"36,-180r-7,0r-6,-90r18,0","w":64},"\"":{"d":"36,-180r-7,0r-6,-90r18,0xm79,-180r-7,0r-5,-90r18,0","w":108},"@":{"d":"292,-112v0,78,-25,99,-89,96r-4,-14v-45,32,-124,18,-116,-60v-7,-78,70,-92,116,-60v3,-5,0,-16,10,-14r0,139v61,2,73,-29,73,-87v0,-67,-32,-105,-123,-105v-91,0,-132,40,-132,127v0,87,41,127,132,127v34,0,72,-7,92,-14r0,10v-24,8,-56,14,-92,14v-100,0,-143,-47,-143,-137v0,-90,43,-137,143,-137v96,0,133,39,133,115xm198,-39r0,-102v-40,-32,-115,-13,-104,51v-11,64,63,83,104,51","w":308},"$":{"d":"94,-31v54,0,80,-12,80,-42v0,-33,-25,-34,-71,-38v-54,-5,-83,-7,-83,-43v0,-40,42,-52,102,-50r15,-43r10,0r-16,44v20,2,40,5,49,9r0,10v-10,-4,-44,-11,-73,-11v-52,0,-76,9,-76,41v0,28,26,30,72,33v55,4,82,9,82,48v0,38,-37,54,-101,52r-15,43r-10,0r16,-44v-21,-2,-44,-6,-54,-10r0,-9v10,4,44,10,73,10","w":205},"#":{"d":"29,0r20,-66r-40,0r3,-10r39,0r22,-73r-40,0r3,-10r40,0r20,-66r12,0r-20,66r68,0r20,-66r12,0r-20,66r40,0r-3,10r-40,0r-22,73r40,0r-3,10r-40,0r-19,66r-12,0r20,-66r-69,0r-19,66r-12,0xm85,-149r-22,73r68,0r22,-73r-68,0"},"0":{"d":"194,-113v0,77,-19,115,-86,115v-67,0,-86,-38,-86,-115v0,-77,19,-114,86,-114v67,0,86,37,86,114xm183,-113v0,-72,-18,-104,-75,-104v-57,0,-75,32,-75,104v0,72,18,105,75,105v57,0,75,-33,75,-105"},"1":{"d":"10,-210v22,-5,40,-14,64,-17r0,227r-11,0r0,-216r-53,12r0,-6","w":122},"2":{"d":"157,-168v0,-55,-83,-56,-127,-40r0,-10v14,-5,36,-9,59,-9v64,0,79,28,79,59v0,38,-16,60,-140,159r142,0r0,9r-157,0r0,-6v127,-104,144,-125,144,-162","w":186},"3":{"d":"73,-217v-19,0,-38,5,-53,9r0,-11v15,-5,37,-8,53,-8v62,0,80,29,80,69v0,27,-11,58,-50,62v44,1,59,34,59,67v0,41,-17,76,-86,76v-24,0,-43,-5,-56,-10r0,-9v13,5,32,9,56,9v63,0,75,-31,75,-66v0,-57,-45,-64,-105,-61r0,-10r32,0v51,0,63,-30,63,-58v0,-33,-10,-59,-68,-59","w":178},"4":{"d":"155,-227r0,173r40,0r0,9r-40,0r0,90r-11,0r0,-90r-128,0r0,-6r133,-176r6,0xm30,-54r114,0r0,-150","w":208},"5":{"d":"163,-40v0,100,-89,95,-147,77r0,-10v53,17,136,23,136,-67v0,-84,-61,-64,-126,-67r0,-118r131,0r0,9r-121,0r0,100v69,-2,127,-10,127,76","w":174},"6":{"d":"170,-262r0,10v-19,-7,-31,-10,-57,-10v-72,0,-83,65,-82,142v8,-37,36,-51,72,-51v67,0,76,42,76,86v0,43,-13,87,-76,87v-67,0,-81,-39,-81,-130v0,-90,18,-144,91,-144v30,0,44,5,57,10xm34,-84v0,40,12,76,69,76v52,0,65,-35,65,-77v0,-42,-9,-77,-65,-77v-60,0,-69,46,-69,78","w":198},"7":{"d":"46,45r-11,0r107,-261r-137,0r0,-9r146,0r0,9","w":156,"k":{"4":22}},"8":{"d":"101,-272v96,0,95,120,30,131v33,3,55,26,55,70v0,43,-22,73,-85,73v-63,0,-86,-30,-86,-73v0,-44,23,-67,56,-70v-28,-6,-46,-25,-46,-62v0,-41,19,-69,76,-69xm101,-8v58,0,74,-28,74,-63v0,-46,-24,-64,-74,-64v-50,0,-74,18,-74,64v0,35,16,63,74,63xm101,-145v49,0,64,-24,64,-58v0,-33,-11,-59,-64,-59v-53,0,-65,26,-65,59v0,34,16,58,65,58","w":201},"9":{"d":"29,37r0,-10v19,7,31,10,57,10v72,1,82,-65,81,-142v-8,37,-35,51,-71,51v-67,0,-76,-42,-76,-86v0,-43,13,-87,76,-87v67,0,81,39,81,130v0,90,-18,144,-91,144v-30,0,-44,-5,-57,-10xm165,-141v0,-40,-12,-76,-69,-76v-52,0,-65,35,-65,77v0,42,9,77,65,77v60,0,69,-46,69,-78","w":198},"%":{"d":"80,-90v-42,0,-60,-21,-60,-69v0,-48,18,-68,60,-68v41,0,60,20,60,68v0,48,-19,69,-60,69xm80,-100v32,0,49,-16,49,-59v0,-43,-17,-58,-49,-58v-33,0,-49,15,-49,58v0,43,16,59,49,59xm103,0r-13,0r159,-225r13,0xm273,-135v42,0,60,21,60,69v0,48,-18,68,-60,68v-41,0,-60,-20,-60,-68v0,-48,19,-69,60,-69xm273,-125v-32,0,-49,16,-49,59v0,43,17,58,49,58v33,0,48,-15,48,-58v0,-43,-15,-59,-48,-59","w":352},"+":{"d":"113,-53r-10,0r0,-65r-65,0r0,-10r65,0r0,-65r10,0r0,65r65,0r0,10r-65,0r0,65"},"=":{"d":"178,-153r0,10r-140,0r0,-10r140,0xm178,-102r0,10r-140,0r0,-10r140,0"},"<":{"d":"178,-52r0,12r-140,-79r0,-7r140,-79r0,12r-128,70"},">":{"d":"38,-40r0,-12r128,-71r-128,-70r0,-12r140,79r0,7"},"\u00a0":{"w":61,"k":{"T":11,"V":7,"W":7,"Y":4}}}});

Cufon.registerFont({"w":195,"face":{"font-family":"Apex","font-weight":550,"font-stretch":"normal","units-per-em":"360","panose-1":"2 1 6 0 4 5 1 1 1 3","ascent":"270","descent":"-90","x-height":"4","bbox":"-18 -294.312 347 94","underline-thickness":"9","underline-position":"-27.36","unicode-range":"U+0020-U+007E"},"glyphs":{" ":{"w":72,"k":{"T":11,"V":7,"W":7,"Y":4}},"A":{"d":"177,0r-19,-66r-86,0r-19,66r-44,0r86,-273r41,0r85,273r-44,0xm150,-99r-35,-120r-34,120r69,0","w":230,"k":{"T":34,"V":32,"W":22,"Y":47,"C":7,"G":7,"O":7,"Q":7,"S":7,"v":20,"w":7,"y":18,"c":4,"d":4,"e":4,"o":4,"q":4,"U":7}},"B":{"d":"22,0r0,-270r91,0v66,0,85,32,85,74v0,23,-11,43,-32,53v26,8,41,33,41,64v0,45,-22,79,-92,79r-93,0xm62,-123r0,86r54,0v38,0,47,-21,47,-43v0,-50,-54,-44,-101,-43xm155,-194v0,-18,-6,-39,-41,-39r-52,0r0,76r53,0v32,0,40,-20,40,-37","w":218,"k":{"V":11,"W":4,"Y":7,"X":7}},"C":{"d":"18,-135v0,-89,32,-139,112,-139v32,0,50,6,63,11r0,39v-70,-30,-133,-10,-133,89v0,98,63,120,133,89r0,39v-13,5,-31,11,-63,11v-80,0,-112,-50,-112,-139","w":211,"k":{"T":7,"Y":11,"A":4}},"D":{"d":"102,0r-80,0r0,-270r80,0v90,0,115,58,115,135v0,77,-25,135,-115,135xm62,-233r0,196v79,8,113,-21,113,-98v0,-77,-34,-107,-113,-98","w":234,"k":{"T":7,"V":11,"W":7,"Y":25,"A":11,"X":11}},"E":{"d":"175,-158r0,37r-113,0r0,84r124,0r0,37r-164,0r0,-270r164,0r0,37r-124,0r0,75r113,0","w":203,"k":{"J":-5,"j":-5}},"F":{"d":"172,-157r0,37r-110,0r0,120r-40,0r0,-270r161,0r0,37r-121,0r0,76r110,0","k":{".":36,",":36,":":13,";":13,"A":22,"J":22,"v":7,"w":7,"y":7,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"g":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"X":7}},"G":{"d":"128,4v-80,0,-110,-54,-110,-139v0,-85,30,-139,111,-139v37,0,63,6,78,14r0,39v-25,-10,-47,-16,-73,-16v-55,0,-74,38,-74,102v0,84,45,117,113,96r0,-73r-48,0r0,-37r88,0r0,137v-14,8,-46,16,-85,16","w":234,"k":{"T":7,"Y":7,"A":4}},"H":{"d":"212,0r-40,0r0,-121r-110,0r0,121r-40,0r0,-270r40,0r0,112r110,0r0,-112r40,0r0,270","w":234},"I":{"d":"68,0r-40,0r0,-270r40,0r0,270","w":95},"J":{"d":"8,0r0,-39v21,8,61,9,61,-23r0,-208r40,0r0,214v5,49,-48,69,-101,56","w":134},"K":{"d":"167,0r-83,-119r-22,26r0,93r-40,0r0,-270r40,0r0,125r97,-125r50,0r-100,120r109,150r-51,0","w":224,"k":{"V":7,"W":7,"Y":7,"C":14,"G":14,"O":14,"Q":14,"S":7,"v":29,"w":22,"y":22,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"l":7,"f":18,"i":7,"t":22,"u":7,"x":7,"z":7}},"L":{"d":"62,-270r0,233r118,0r0,37r-158,0r0,-270r40,0","w":188,"k":{"T":36,"V":47,"W":36,"Y":52,"C":18,"G":18,"O":18,"Q":18,"v":25,"w":18,"X":7}},"M":{"d":"233,-203r-67,166r-38,0r-68,-166r2,203r-40,0r0,-270r52,0r73,184r73,-184r52,0r0,270r-41,0","w":293},"N":{"d":"215,0r-37,0r-117,-192r1,192r-40,0r0,-270r37,0r117,192r-1,-192r40,0r0,270","w":236},"O":{"d":"122,4v-87,0,-104,-63,-104,-139v0,-76,17,-139,104,-139v87,0,104,63,104,139v0,76,-17,139,-104,139xm122,-238v-51,0,-62,39,-62,103v0,64,11,103,62,103v51,0,63,-39,63,-103v0,-64,-12,-103,-63,-103","w":244,"k":{"T":14,"V":7,"Y":11,"A":7,"X":7}},"P":{"d":"62,-101r0,101r-40,0r0,-270r87,0v69,0,93,41,93,85v0,44,-24,84,-93,84r-47,0xm62,-233r0,95r49,0v40,0,47,-27,47,-47v0,-20,-7,-48,-47,-48r-49,0","w":208,"k":{".":50,",":50,"V":11,"W":4,"Y":7,"A":27,"v":5,"w":4,"a":11,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"g":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"X":7,"u":4,"z":7,"m":7,"n":7,"p":7,"r":7}},"Q":{"d":"226,-135v1,62,-10,109,-56,128r84,17r0,41r-168,-51v-56,-17,-68,-69,-68,-135v0,-80,18,-139,104,-139v86,0,104,59,104,139xm122,-238v-51,0,-62,39,-62,103v0,64,11,103,62,103v51,0,63,-39,63,-103v0,-64,-12,-103,-63,-103","w":244,"k":{"T":14,"V":7,"Y":11,"A":7,"X":7}},"R":{"d":"62,-110r0,110r-40,0r0,-270r88,0v70,0,92,31,92,80v0,35,-11,60,-44,72r57,118r-48,0r-49,-110r-56,0xm62,-233r0,86r54,0v37,0,42,-21,42,-43v0,-22,-5,-43,-42,-43r-54,0","w":223,"k":{"T":14,"V":14,"Y":14}},"S":{"d":"110,-157v56,8,89,20,89,75v0,51,-31,86,-103,86v-27,0,-62,-6,-80,-15r0,-40v15,6,41,17,78,17v49,0,63,-19,63,-45v0,-30,-13,-37,-49,-42v-66,-8,-92,-26,-92,-75v0,-40,23,-78,96,-78v35,0,59,6,73,13r0,39v-34,-20,-127,-24,-127,26v0,29,16,34,52,39","w":214,"k":{"T":11,"V":7,"W":7,"Y":11,"A":7,"X":7,"Z":7}},"T":{"d":"190,-233r-70,0r0,233r-40,0r0,-233r-70,0r0,-37r180,0r0,37","w":200,"k":{".":32,",":32,":":32,";":32,"A":29,"C":11,"G":11,"J":22,"O":11,"Q":11,"v":29,"w":29,"y":29,"a":32,"c":32,"d":32,"e":32,"g":32,"o":32,"q":32,"s":32," ":11,"j":7,"f":18,"i":7,"t":18,"u":29,"x":29,"z":29,"m":29,"n":29,"p":29,"r":29}},"U":{"d":"118,4v-37,0,-98,-13,-98,-89r0,-185r40,0r0,181v0,51,36,57,58,57v22,0,58,-6,58,-57r0,-181r40,0r0,185v0,76,-61,89,-98,89","w":236,"k":{"A":7}},"V":{"d":"177,-270r44,0r-85,273r-41,0r-86,-273r44,0r62,220","w":230,"k":{".":36,",":36,":":27,";":27,"A":32,"C":7,"G":7,"O":7,"Q":7,"v":13,"w":13,"y":13,"a":32,"c":29,"d":29,"e":29,"g":29,"o":29,"q":29,"s":25," ":11,"f":7,"t":7,"u":14,"x":13,"z":13,"m":13,"n":13,"p":13,"r":13}},"W":{"d":"88,-57r46,-213r50,0r46,213r35,-213r43,0r-51,273r-49,0r-49,-225r-49,225r-49,0r-51,-273r43,0","w":318,"k":{".":36,",":36,":":27,";":27,"A":22,"a":16,"c":14,"d":14,"e":14,"g":14,"o":14,"q":14,"s":14," ":11,"t":7,"u":7,"z":7,"m":14,"n":14,"p":14,"r":14}},"X":{"d":"114,-162r59,-108r48,0r-79,132r82,138r-49,0r-61,-109r-60,109r-49,0r82,-138r-79,-132r48,0","w":235,"k":{"C":7,"G":7,"O":7,"Q":7,"v":14,"w":11,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"o":7,"q":7,"s":7,"x":7,"z":7,"m":7,"n":7,"p":7,"r":7}},"Y":{"d":"233,-270r-92,162r0,108r-41,0r0,-108r-92,-162r46,0r67,126r66,-126r46,0","w":241,"k":{".":43,",":43,":":34,";":34,"A":47,"C":14,"G":14,"J":29,"O":14,"Q":14,"S":11,"v":29,"w":29,"y":29,"a":50,"c":45,"d":45,"e":45,"g":45,"o":45,"q":45,"s":40,"l":5," ":7,"j":13,"f":25,"i":13,"t":25,"u":29,"x":29,"z":29,"m":29,"n":29,"p":29,"r":29}},"Z":{"d":"209,0r-198,0r0,-27r138,-205r-129,1r0,-39r183,0r0,27r-138,205r144,-1r0,39","w":219,"k":{"v":14,"w":14,"y":14,"f":7,"t":7}},"a":{"d":"120,-115v12,-50,-68,-35,-92,-24r0,-35v14,-6,38,-10,59,-10v109,-3,63,99,73,184r-24,0r-6,-14v-14,12,-35,18,-55,18v-46,0,-62,-28,-62,-57v0,-55,53,-60,107,-62xm120,-87v-28,5,-67,-2,-67,32v0,32,50,30,67,14r0,-46","w":178},"b":{"d":"60,-170v58,-35,120,-3,120,80v0,59,-19,94,-72,94v-24,0,-42,-6,-58,-18r-6,14r-24,0r0,-270r40,0r0,100xm99,-150v-19,0,-32,6,-39,10r0,100v7,4,20,10,39,10v35,0,41,-27,41,-60v0,-33,-6,-60,-41,-60","k":{"v":4,"w":7,"y":7,"x":7}},"c":{"d":"55,-90v0,35,10,59,45,59v21,0,35,-4,48,-9r0,35v-14,6,-31,9,-50,9v-64,0,-83,-38,-83,-94v0,-56,19,-94,83,-94v19,0,36,3,50,9r0,35v-13,-5,-27,-9,-48,-9v-35,0,-45,24,-45,59","w":162},"d":{"d":"15,-90v0,-82,60,-115,120,-80r0,-100r40,0r0,270r-23,0r-7,-14v-16,12,-34,18,-58,18v-53,0,-72,-35,-72,-94xm96,-150v-35,0,-41,27,-41,60v0,33,6,60,41,60v19,0,32,-6,39,-10r0,-100v-7,-4,-20,-10,-39,-10"},"e":{"d":"15,-90v0,-58,21,-94,80,-94v70,0,75,51,72,109r-112,0v-9,50,70,51,105,34r0,34v-21,9,-45,11,-64,11v-60,0,-81,-36,-81,-94xm95,-149v-30,0,-39,19,-40,46r72,0v0,-24,-1,-46,-32,-46","w":183,"k":{"v":4,"w":4,"y":7,"x":7}},"f":{"d":"138,-270r0,34v-21,-5,-60,-8,-60,24r0,32r51,0r0,34r-51,0r0,146r-40,0r0,-146r-33,0r0,-25r33,-9v-4,-60,6,-95,70,-94v12,0,23,1,30,4","w":137,"k":{".":22,",":22,"a":7,"c":7,"d":7,"e":7,"o":7,"q":7}},"g":{"d":"158,-147v20,59,-14,110,-91,98v-8,7,-7,19,6,21v47,6,113,2,113,58v0,46,-49,64,-101,64v-48,0,-83,-15,-83,-52v0,-24,19,-39,38,-45v-21,-11,-15,-44,2,-54v-50,-33,-39,-127,46,-127v13,0,24,1,33,4r63,0r0,26xm148,31v-1,-28,-48,-19,-72,-26v-18,3,-35,12,-35,29v0,20,14,28,47,28v32,0,60,-9,60,-31xm51,-116v0,21,7,36,37,36v30,0,37,-15,37,-36v0,-21,-7,-36,-37,-36v-30,0,-37,15,-37,36","w":188},"h":{"d":"130,-123v4,-37,-53,-28,-70,-17r0,140r-....
```

Comment: IMO it's the font you have chosen to display your text with. I think most fonts implement latin1 and the scandinav characters are not there. Try another font (e.g. use the one used by stackoverflow "Consolas")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that @equinoxel is right, the fonts you have chosen don't have coverage for the characters you want.

According to the [Cufón FAQ #3 "Some characters do not show up at all!"](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ#wiki-faq-3), the cause of this is, "Either you are not using UTF-8 or your font does not support the characters you need (or you simply forgot to include them when you generated the font)...." The solution is, "Make sure your pages are UTF-8 encoded and that you’ve selected the appropriate glyph ranges. Basic Latin should be enough for most English-only sites. Combine Basic Latin with Latin-1 Supplement and you cover most European languages."

You don't include the CSS for your page, so I'm not sure exactly which fonts are invoked. Nor do you include all of the second font.  However, I do observe that both fonts you post have the text `"unicode-range":"U+0020-U+007E"`. This does not include the accented vowels which are dropping out.

Also, I note the page text for the message which displays correctly is `{% trans %}DISTRIBUTOR{% endtrans %}`, while the page text for the message which drops characters is `<strong class="title">{% trans %}FOLLOW US{% endtrans %}</strong>`. The `<strong>` element may be selecting a different font, which does not have the correct characters.

Try dropping the `<strong>` from around the `{% trans %}FOLLOW US{% endtrans %}`. If the Ö character appears, that's a strong (heh, heh) indication that your font doesn't have sufficient glyph coverage.

Comment: You're likely right and for a start I just removed the cufon and the font is still acceptable so I will go without a custom font to not have this problem. If I can find the font I might make a new cufon to include more foreign characters, but it's such a time-consuming project for a very little change when it looks OK even without the cufon.